# International to domestic connection on Turkish Airlines

Tags: turkish-airlines

We are traveling from Tbilisi to Ataturk airport and then with a transit to Antalya; both legs were sold under a single ticket by Turkish Airlines.

- Do they automatically put luggage for transit?
- How far is the second terminal, and where we should go for passport control?

Comment: Hi, welcome to Travel.SE! Can you please clarify if your journey is sold by Turkish airlines as one ticket, or two separate tickets? The answer to your question will differ depending on your answer to this.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your answer. Both ways (including transfer) is written in one ticket.

Comment: I've edited the question to reflect your comment, hopefully someone who have a definitive answer can provide it.

Answer (score 3):

For International to Domestic connections on Turkish Airlines, your bags will be automatically transferred to the domestic flight IF (and only if!) the domestic destination you are travelling to has customs facilities at the airport.

In the case of Antalya, they DO have such facilities, so your bags will be automatically transferred to your domestic flight.

Shortly before landing into Istanbul an announcement will be made on the flight, and they will direct you to the back of the in-flight SkyLife magazine to confirm which locations do and do not have customs facilities, so you can use this to confirm what I've said above.

Upon landing in Istanbul you will need to proceed through Passport Control (just follow the signs), through baggage claim and customs (WITHOUT collecting your bags), and then make an immediate LEFT turn and follow the signs to the domestic terminal which is a 5-10 minute walk away.

Answer (score -1):

- I just always ask about luggage at the check-in when I drop it off to be extra sure. I expect that it would be transferred automatically in your case.
- There is no way that you will miss the passport control (just follow the signs), and Ataturk is a single large building so different places in it can't be very far.

Comment: (-1) because the first part of this answer is “I don’t know, ask someone else.” The second part is a false statement: Ataturk airport has two terminals which are separate buildings.

Comment: It's virtually impossible to get lost or confused in the international terminal at Ataturk. But everything past passport and customs is much more complex. I think a better explanation of how to pass through the airport terminals would be useful.